# Add rows to a binded datagridview1

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview1 which is databound through a BindingSource to a dataset

```
dim dt as datatable
dim bsData as bindingsource

bsData.DataSource = dt
DataGridView1.DataSource = bsData
```

I also have rows from another datatable `dt5` that I need to add to the datagridview1 datatable

My code below creates a new column in datagridview1 called `Objectives` but it doesn't add the rows values(H1) from `dt5`

any idea ? appreciated

```
Dim dt5 As New DataTable
        dt5.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)
        Dim mybindingsource As BindingSource = CType(DataGridView1.DataSource, BindingSource)
        Dim dtts As DataTable = CType(mybindingsource.DataSource, DataTable)
        dtts.Columns.Add("Objectives")
        Dim newrow As DataRow
        For i = 0 To (dt5.DefaultView.Count - 1)
            newrow = dtts.NewRow

            newrow.Item("Objectives") = dt5.Rows.Item(i).Item("H1")
            dtts.Rows.Add(newrow)
        next
```

Comment: this code actually add the new row with H1 value at the end of the datagridview1 rows. what I need is to add a new column and add H1 to the begining of the new column

Comment: Did `dt` has Objectives column or not? Do you auto-populate the columns?

Comment: yes the columns are selected from an excel sheet with the headers.

Comment: No sorry, I added that column with 'dtts.Columns.Add("Objectives")'

Comment: Have u tried to refresh the datagrid after adding?

Comment: The daragrid get updated every 7 min, nothing changed! like I said the newrow get loaded to the last row of the datagrid. I want the data to be loaded to the new column "Objectives"

Comment: OK, if that's the case try to re-bind the DataGrid again. Set the datasource to null, and then set it back to the bsData. Can you tell me why do you use bindingsource?